# correlation matrix filtering based on high variables correlation with selection of least correlated with target variable at scale using vectors

Tags: python, numpy

I have this resulting correlation matrix:

| id | row | col | corr | target_corr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | b | 0.95 | 0.2 |
| 1 | a | c | 0.7 | 0.2 |
| 2 | a | d | 0.2 | 0.2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | b | a | 0.95 | 0.7 |
| 4 | b | c | 0.35 | 0.7 |
| 5 | b | d | 0.65 | 0.7 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | c | a | 0.7 | 0.6 |
| 7 | c | b | 0.35 | 0.6 |
| 8 | c | d | 0.02 | 0.6 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 | d | a | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| 10 | d | b | 0.65 | 0.3 |
| 11 | d | c | 0.02 | 0.3 |
|  |  |  |  |  |

> After filtering high correlated variables based on "corr" variable I
> try to add new column that will compare will decide to mark "keep" the
> least correlated variable from "row" or mark "drop" of that variable
> for the most correlated variable "target_corr" column. In other works
> from corelated variables matching cut > 0.5 select the one least correlated to
> "target_corr":

**Expected result:**

| id | row | col | corr | target_corr | drop/keep |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | b | 0.95 | 0.2 | keep |
| 1 | a | c | 0.7 | 0.2 | keep |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | b | a | 0.95 | 0.7 | drop |
| 3 | b | d | 0.65 | 0.7 | drop |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | c | a | 0.7 | 0.6 | drop |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 | d | b | 0.65 | 0.3 | keep |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

---

> This approach does use very large dataframes so resulting corr matrix for example is > 100kx100k and generated using pyspark:

```
def corrwith_matrix_no_save(df, data_cols=None, select_targets = None, method='pearson'):
    from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
    from pyspark.ml.stat import Correlation
    from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics
    
    start_time = time.time()
    vector_col = "corr_features"
    if data_cols == None and select_targets == None:
        data_cols = df.columns
        select_target = list(df.columns)
        assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=data_cols, outputCol=vector_col)
        df_vector = assembler.transform(df).select(vector_col)
        matrix = Correlation.corr(df_vector, vector_col, method)

        result = matrix.collect()[0]["pearson({})".format(vector_col)].values
    
        final_df = pd.DataFrame(result.reshape(-1, len(data_cols)), columns=data_cols, index=data_cols)
        final_df = final_df.apply(lambda x: x.abs() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else x )
        corr_df = final_df[select_target]
        #corr_df.columns = [str(col) + '_corr' for col in corr_df.columns]
        corr_df['column_names'] = corr_df.index
        
    print('Execution time for correlation_matrix function:', time.time() - start_time)
    
    return corr_df
```

> created the dataframe from uper triagle with [numpy.triu](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html)and [numpy.stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) + added the target column my merging 2 resulting dataframes (if code is required can provide but will increase the content a lot so will provide only if needs clarifcation).

```
def corrX_to_ls(corr_mtx) :
    # Get correlation matrix and upper triagle
        df_target = corr_mtx['target']
        corr_df = corr_mtx.drop('target', inplace=True)

        up = corr_df.where(np.triu(np.ones(corr_df.shape), k=1).astype(np.bool))
        print('This is triu: \n', up )
    
        df = up.stack().reset_index()
        df.columns = ['row','col','corr']
        df_lsDF = df.query("row" != "col")
        df_target_corr = df_target.reset_index()
        df_target_corr.columns = ['target_col', 'target_corr']
        sample_df = df_lsDF.merge(df_target_corr, how='left', left_ob='row', right_on='target_col')
        sample_df = sample_df.drop('target_col', 1)

    return (sample_df)
```

> Now after filtering resulting dataframe based on `df.Corr > cut where cut > 0.50` got stuck at marking what variable o keep and what to drop
> ( I do look to mark them only then select into a list variables) ...
> so help on solving it will be greatly appreciated and will also
> benefit community when working on distributed system.

> Note: Looking for example/solution to scale so I can distribute
> operations on executors so lists or like a group/subset of the
> dataframe to be done in parallel and avoid loops is what I do look, so
> [numpy.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and/or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)
> approaches is what I do look.

> Additional "thinking" from top of my mind:  I do think on grouping by
> `"row" column` so can distribute processing each group on executors or
> by using lists distribute processing in parallel on executors so each
> list will generate a job for each thread from `ThreadPool` ( I done
> done this approach for column vectors but for very large
> matrix/dataframes can become inefficient so for rows I think will
> work).

Comment: This line doesn't seem to be correct `final_df = pd.DataFrame(result.reshape(-1, len(data_cols)), columns=data_cols, index=data_cols)`. That said, what is this `final_df` in your question, the sample input or the expected output?

Comment: sample input, that function I provided on how I do generate the corr matrix so adding function to generate the sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `final_df` as the sample input, you can try:

```
# filter
output = final_df.query('corr>target_corr').copy()

# assign drop/keep
output['drop_keep'] = np.where(output['corr']>2*output['target_corr'],
                               'keep','drop')
```

Output:

```
    id row col  corr  target_corr drop_keep
0    0   a   b  0.95          0.2      keep
1    1   a   c  0.70          0.2      keep
3    3   b   a  0.95          0.7      drop
6    6   c   a  0.70          0.6      drop
10  10   d   b  0.65          0.3      keep
```

Comment: is anyway to perform in parallel this filtering, please ? like by groups of column row ? because this approach will not scale and will do all computations on the driver ( I try to use this approach for more than this corr matrix)

Comment: As far as I can see, there is nothing special about this filtering. All can be done on the nodes, unless you don't have the `target_corr` distributed. I'm not familiar with PySpark to say more on this topics, sorry.

Comment: figured out, this approach put into a function and using ThreadPool() to distribute jobs in parallel so each group is a small df that can be filtered in parallel then join distributed results and reset distributed index. I was overcomplicating simple stuff ... Thank u a lot for help!